# Develop same c++ project, multiple machines, different visual studio versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I know that the question was asked many times, but I can find only the answer to the first part (having multiple machines). I've this situation:

A) Desktop PC: Windows XP Pro x86 - Visual Studio 2008

B) Laptop PC: Windows 7 Pro x64 - Visual Studio 2010

I think of using something like Mercurial (I've never worked with it before, but seems a good solution) , to keep the source code updated between the PCs. 
My question is: when on the machine A, for example I add a new file to the project, so to the VS 2008 project, is there a way to auto-update the VS 2010 project too or something similar?

many thanks in advance,
Juri

Comment: VS11 will support round-tripping with VS2010 solutions and projects, but not VS2010 with VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a version control system (Mercurial, SVN Git..). And you could use CMake 
http://www.cmake.org/ to generate different VS Solutions from your project.